# Adjective phrase

Tags: phrases, adjectives

> But with the advent of cheaper to undertake, safer, easier, and open to anyone rail and steamship travel, the tradition had no longer become a privilege of the aristocrat and the upper class._

Is it possible to say *open to anyone railroad and steamship travel*?
As far as I know of, such adjective phrases modify a following noun. What would be a good grammatical explanation for this one?

Comment: I'm deeply suspicious of [***had no longer become***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22had+no+longer+become%22) there. True, there are a few hundred written instances of the word sequence in Google Books, but that must be balanced against tens of millions of instances of what I'd have expected: [***was no longer***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+no+longer%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, it is odd. Perhaps antiquated? I agree that _was no longer_ is a much better phrase.

Comment: @Oliver: Over the decades I've read a *lot* of English text from Shakespeare onwards (never really took to Chaucer "in the original"). I can't say the cited form here strikes me as in any way "old-fashioned" - it's just ***clumsy***. Anyway, nothing about [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+no+longer+become&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chad%20no%20longer%20become%3B%2Cc0) suggests it was significantly more common in the past.

Comment: ...note that the apparent "spike" in usage around 1827 seems to be just 6 different sources citing one occurrence in a parliamentary debate (which is actually dated 1866, so I think there's a coding error somewhere in the data presentation).

Comment: Yes, it's possible and I think rather nice. Syntactically, "open to anyone rail and steamship travel" is a noun phrase with the nominal "rail and steamship travel" as head, and the AdjP "open to anyone" as pre-head modifier.

Comment: @BillJ 43: Then, is “open to anyone” used as a compound word? If so, is open-to-anyone better?

Comment: Yes, it could indeed be hyphenated and thus be a morphological compound rather than a syntactic construction.  It would still be an adjective, though, modifying the nominal "rail and steamship travel".

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I would definitely hyphenate *cheaper-to-undertake* and *open-to-anyone*.

Answer (score 1):

When used as adjectives in a list like this, it's helpful to hyphenate.

> cheaper-to-undertake, safer, easier, and open-to-anyone rail and steamship travel

However, I think long lists of adjectives before a noun phrase are awkward and confusing, especially when they include adjective phrases, since it takes so long to reach the object being discussed. So it would be better to rephrase:

> But with the advent of rail and steamship travel that is cheaper to undertake, safer, easier, and open to anyone, ...

Answer (score 0):

But with the advent of cheaper, to undertake safer, easier, and open-to-anyone railroad and steamship travel, the...

Seems appropriate to me.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense to me; I read this as "the advent of cheaper-to-undertake, safer, easier, and open-to-anyone rail and steamship travel..."